# Formatting string - money value

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm trying to format my `double` to be in US dollar currency format, but I do not want trailing `00`'s if the value comes out to be a whole number.

I have tried

```
String.Format("{0:#,0.#0}", cost);
```

and

```
String.Format("{0:#,0.##}", cost);
```

The former is leaving me trailing `00` on whole number, and the latter is will give me `55.6` where I want `55.60`. How can I format my value to meet both of these needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with a standard format string, but a trick would be:

```
Regex.Replace(String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", cost),"\\.00$","");
```

or:

```
string s = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", cost);

if (s.EndsWith(".00"))
   s = s.Substring(0,s.Length-3);
```

I know, it's ugly...

Comment: Haha, hey, it gets the job done. Thx. ps - are you forgetting the caret in `"\\.00$"`? `"^\\.00$"`

Comment: Oh I get it, the dollar sign means nothing passed, but there can be something before the . so you leave out the caret

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var output = string.Format(((Math.Round(num) == num) ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}"), num);
```

Comment: The first format string has the same problem as the OP's second example: it truncates 55.60 to 55.6. Your second example works, however. You should edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string val = decimal.Parse("2.00").ToString("G29")


?decimal.Parse("2.00").ToString("G29")
"2"
?decimal.Parse("2.02").ToString("G29")
"2.02"
?decimal.Parse("12.0045").ToString("G29")
"12.0045"
?decimal.Parse("0.0045").ToString("G29")
"0.0045"
?decimal.Parse("0.00").ToString("G29")
"0"
?decimal.Parse("0.05").ToString("G29")
"0.05"
```

Comment: Have you tested this on a variety of different numbers?

Comment: +1: Just tested it myself, and it appears to work. Nice solution.

Comment: You should also clarify the the `29` is a precision specifier. If OP only wants a maximum of two decimal places, the format would be `G3`, etc.

Comment: This isn't going to work for me. I need to parse `double` not `string`. Also, I don't see a test for say `2.1` to be `2.10`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Currency ("C") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString) by calling `ToString`. No actual work required.

Example

```
string s = cost.ToString("C0"); // Where 0 is the precision
```

You can't do anything conditional in a single call like omit precision display, but you could do it through some extension methods.

```
static class CurrencyExtensions
{
    public static String ToCurrency(this decimal d) { // Extend Decimal
        if (d % 1 != 0) return d.ToString("C2");
        return d.ToString("C0");
    }

    public static String ToCurrency(this double d) { // Extend Double
        if (d % 1 != 0) return d.ToString("C2");
        return d.ToString("C0");
    }
}
```

Example Usage

```
decimal amount1 = 4m;
decimal amount2 = 4.25m;

string s1 = amount1.ToCurrency(); // $4
string s2 = amount2.ToCurrency(); // $4.25
```

The advantage of doing it this way over others is that it handles culture information for you, and is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will have to come back to this one. How does this extend the classes? With the `this` parameter?

Comment: They're called `Extension Methods`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx